# How to make a Field Section appear first?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I have a page template that inherits multiple data templates.

Take for example: `Event Page`

which inherits: `Basic Page`, `HasDateRange`, and `HasLocation`

Now, I want the Date Range field group of the `HasDateRange` template to appear first when editing Event Pages.  That's a simple example, but in general, how can I influence the field group order on templates when using multiple inheritance?  Let's say I don't need DateRange at the top of one template and at the bottom of another...  I generally have more important fields that need to appear at the top of every template they are included on.

Not sure it matters, but I am using Sitecore version 7.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Template Section items have a `sortorder` field which accepts an integer. That number governs the order in which sections will appear.

[image]

Here's an article from the Sitecore site:
[Sorting sections in templates](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Sorting%20sections%20in%20templates.aspx)

Also, see the following Stack Overflow question:
[Sortorder of Inherited Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977777/sortorder-of-inherited-templates)

Comment: This is great information, now my fields are in a sensible order. Thank you.

Comment: If you want it to be on the top. As Martin mentioned change the sort order to -100. This will make sure the section appears above all.
Check this link: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/change-the-order-that-component-properties-display-in